# SQL query testing tools

Tags: database, testing, automated-tests

I'm working for a company that has a homemade crap testing framework and they asked to do a research in the market to look for something already existent in order to replace it.

The requirements are basically:

1. being able to connect to any database (at least through the known
   protocols)
2. check if a given query returns the expected values (like
   doing assertions)

do you know any tool close to this?

Comment: A few years ago I used tSQLt. But it's only for SQL Server: https://tsqlt.org/

Comment: saw it, I need for more dbs :(